# Reconstructing video bytes at unity client

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I am trying to send a video file from the server to the client in unity with the help of message (1440 bytes at max I can send). Depending on the message from the unity client I am rendering the texture and after encoding I am sending video bytes to the unity client. Then from unity client, I am storing those bytes that in a file but I have seen I can't open that video file from the client. Can you please tell me what may be the reasons behind this?

This is my message from server.

public class RegisterHostMessages : MessageBase //outgoing message from server

```
 {
    public byte[] video;
    public int size;
 }
```

Sending the message by the channel using,

*NetworkServer.SendByChannelToAll(123, msg, channelid);*